# Is there a way for Gmail to recognize line breaks from text from UIapplication.shared.open url

Tags: ios, swift

Gmail client does not recognize line breaks within text from UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)

I have a function that returns a tuple of available email clients (validated by UIApplication.shared.canOpen) and the associated URL. It's for an error reporting feature, so the arguments array contains the text that will autopopulate email fields.

There are no issues with launching any of the three email clients, but gmail is the only one that doesn't process the line breaks. Does gmail use a different method?

```
enum EmailClient {
    case gmail
    case outlook
    case mail

    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .gmail: return "Gmail"
        case .outlook: return "Outlook"
        case .mail: return "Mail"
        }
    }

    //Creates url used by UIapplciation.shared to launch the client and autopopulate the email
    func url(error: CustomError?) -> URL? {

        guard let username = CredentialManager.username,
            let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String else {
                return nil
        }

        let arguments = [
            username,
            UIDevice().modelName,
            UIDevice.current.systemVersion,
            appVersion,
            error?.description ?? "N/A" //When called from the settings page, no error is passed in
        ]

        var urlFormat: String

        switch self {
        case .gmail: urlFormat = "googlegmail:///co?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@"
        case .outlook: urlFormat = "ms-outlook://compose?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@"
        case .mail: urlFormat = "mailto:%@?subject=%@&body=%@"
        }

        return URL(string: String(format: urlFormat, arguments: [
            EMAIL_RECIPIENT,
            EMAIL_SUBJECT.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"),
            String(format: EMAIL_BODY_FORMAT, arguments: arguments).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "%0A")
        ]))
    }
}
```

Comment: case .gmail: urlFormat = "googlegmail://co?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@"  try it with 2 / not 3

Comment: still no change, unfortunately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that using "\r\n" instead of "\n" fixes the problem

Answer (score 1):

**1) Add the the scheme to your info.plist**

We can do this through the beautiful thing that is the Info.plist file. Add a new key called LSApplicationQueriesSchemes as an array. Then you can enter your apps within the array. The Mail app doesn’t need to go in here, presumably because it is an Apple app. Your entry should look like the below

[image]

```
func openGmail(withFrom: String?, withSubject: String?) {

    var gmailUrlString = "googlegmail:///"

    if let from = withFrom {
            gmailUrlString += "co?to=\(from)"
    }

    if let subject = withSubject {
        gmailUrlString += "&subject=\(subject)"
    }

}
```

One last thing we will need to do is URL encode the subject line before we pass it into the URL. We can do this by calling `subjectString?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)` on the string.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, but I'm still not sure why we need to declare an array in the plist? It doesn't look like it's being used anywhere

Comment: LSApplicationQueriesSchemes (Array - iOS) Specifies the URL schemes you want the app to be able to use with the canOpenURL: method of the UIApplication class. For each URL scheme you want your app to use with the canOpenURL: method, add it as a string in this array. Read the canOpenURL: method description for important information about declaring supported schemes and using that method

Comment: I'm currently already using canOpenURL on the final string to validate which email clients are available on the device. My main issue is purely just the gmail client not recognizing the "%0A" that's embedded in the body. I'm trying to implement some of what you did, but xcode doesn't recognize a .urlQueryAllowed so I'm not sure what to do there

Comment: Okay, I got it to work by typing it out. is it necessary for me to have an openGmail openOutlook etc functions? Also, your answer ways that we need to call the addingPercentEncoding method on the subject line, but my primary issue is the body. The subject line doesn't need any linebreaks, while my body contains many. Do I need to applyPercentEncoding to the body and subject separately and then wrap the entire thing around a URL(String(format: urlFormat, argument: [EMAIL_RECIPIENT, EMAIL_SUBJECT.applyPercentEncoding.... , EMAIL_BODY.applyPercentEncoding])) or can I just applyPercentEncoding to

Comment: And by work, I mean that xcode lets me compile, but the email body still doesn't have linebreaks.

Comment: addingPercentEncoding  must be called because you do not know what the body or the subject may contain and the url needs to be encoded in order to be correct.   then about the functions it is a good way according to me to use them, but it is up  to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188118/discussion-between-teachmesenpai-and-enea-dume).

Comment: this does not answer the question "Is there a way for Gmail to recognize line breaks" in any way